# Running Calabash via SSH on Mac iOS Simulator Launch Fails

Tags: ios, macos, ssh, cucumber, calabash

I'm trying to run Calabash test cases on another Mac vis SSH from another Mac. The user I ssh in with is not admin but I've given permission as described at https://superuser.com/questions/166179/how-to-enable-remote-access-for-another-account-on-mac-remotely-via-ssh

So after `bundle exec cucumber` the test cases start to run but the iOS Simulator doesn't launch and it fails with the error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app with error -10810.
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

After `ssh`ing in, try

```
chmod +x /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```